# jiren/filter.js with express and ejs files - conflicts

Tags: javascript, express, filter, ejs

I'm creating an app with express/sequelize and ejs files.
And now i want to use this fantastic solution of filters by Jiren but this solution is using the same syntax as ejs variables.
When i'm including my template with these variables in the script tag `type="text/html"` its trigger me an error (which is not defined but appears at the lines of my include). When i change the template to "john do" the page is displaying but my console brings me the "error JSONquery is not defined" (it's maybe two differents errors i'm not sure but JSONquery is a part of the filter.js plugin). I can show you my template here

```
<script id="artists-template" type="text/html">
    <li 
         class="main__product-list-item" 
         data-height="<%= height %>" 
         data-width="<%= width %>" 
         data-low="<%= yearBegin %>"
         data-high="<%= yearEnd %>" 
         data-name='<%= artist %>' 
         data-longueur='<%= height %>' 
         data-largeur='<%= width%>'
         >
            <figure class="main__product">
             <a class="main__product-image-link" href="/name/<%= id %>">
            <% if(Images.length !== 0) { %>
            <img alt="illustration" src="./img/_thumb<%= Images[0]['adress'] %>.jpg"/>
            <% } else { %>
            <img alt="illustration" src="./img/icon-no-image.svg"/>
            <% } %>
        </a>
        <figcaption class="main__product-description">
            <h3>
               <a href="/name/<%= id %>">
                  <span class="product__title">"<%= title %>" - <%= artist %></span>
                   <span class="product__date">, <span class="product__period"><%= period %></span></span>
                </a>
            </h3>
            <p>
            Créé probablement entre <span class="product__low-date"><%= yearBegin %></span> et <span class="product__high-date"><%= yearEnd %></span>
            <br/>Hauteur : <span class="product__height"><%= height %></span>  cm / Largeur : <span class="product__width"><%= width %></span> cm

            <span class="main__product-description-story"><%= description %></span></p>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
     </li>
 </script>
```

It's the same problem when i inject just one variable like `<%= artist %>`. Here is how i bind my data:

```
<% var datas = JSON.stringify(creations) %>
<script>
    var data = <%- datas %>;
    console.log(data);
 </script>
```

I hope it's just a simple issue and i have to change just a simple character to make it work. At this time I think that the biggest issue is about this "JsonQUERY is not defined" because even if i don't bind my template with datas, the zone which must be filled with the template is actually not bound.
I tried to google the error but i found nothing. If someone have any ideas...thanks.

Here is the website of the filters solution : https://github.com/jiren/filter.js

Answer (score 0):

Hourrayyy !!! I've found the solution, i googled ejs conflicts and found that the point is to change the plug-in syntax: if you encounter the same problem try to change those lines :

```
var templateSettings = {
    evaluate    : /<%([\s\S]+?)%>/g,
    interpolate : /<%=([\s\S]+?)%>/g,
    escape      : /<%-([\s\S]+?)%>/g
 };
```

to these

```
var templateSettings = {
   interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
   escape: /\{\{\-(.+?)\}\}/g,
   evaluate: /\{\%(.+?)\%\}/g
};
```

now i just have to use this syntax : {{ variable }} and its working properly !